# Database of Greyhound bus stops

Tags: data-request, usa, geospatial, transportation, canada

Greyhound bus stops are surprisingly [difficult to find](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44143/map-of-bus-stops-for-greyhound-in-canada). Is there a database of them?

Requirements:

- Bus stop name
- Latitude
- Longitude
- Lines that stop there, or adjacent stops.

I am interested in all of their stops, not only those in the USA (datasets for USA stops are better than nothing, though).

All I could find is [this difficult-to-reuse map](http://extranet.greyhound.com/Revsup/schedules/sa-50.pdf) and [this painful locator](https://www.greyhound.ca/en/locations/default.aspx).

Comment: Also this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Greyhound_Bus_stations

Comment: @philshem - that Wikipedia page only has about 2 dozen locations. Greyhound's site says they have 3100 stops, some of which will handle ticketing and package express.

Comment: It seems to me that we should find a why to contact Greyhound corporate and have them make the location information 'dataset friendly' for mobile application developers.

Comment: From personal experience, I can assure you that that difficult-to-reuse map is incomplete.  I've been on plenty of Greyhound-affiliated buses not shown on that map.

Answer (score 4):

i think this is a good start, but i can't find who authored it. i would take the kml from this map and upload it to geojson.io where you can fiddle and convert it more.
https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?msa=0&mid=zzToj9iDb7Q0.kZhGp83_3Et8

edit:
the wayback machine has what you want albeit a year old. i only checked texas, so maybe i'm wrong. go here and then swap out state two letter digits.
http://web.archive.org/web/20131212034714/http://www.greyhound.com/en/locations/locations.aspx?state=tx

canada locations by province:
http://web.archive.org/web/20130817065113/http://greyhound.ca/en/locations/states.aspx

also there's this but you'll have to filter out mexico:
http://www.routefriend.com/stations/greyhound

Comment: Including Mexico information is OK, actually I am interested in all of their destinations, and only said "USA+Canada" to point out it is not USA-only.